# Can we 301 redirect to a new page, but still publish the old content somewhere else?

Tags: seo, google-search, 301-redirect, search-results

We have a page on the site which ranks well for an SEO term (top 5) but contains old information. We have added a new page but Google doesn't rank it that well. Information on these pages is time sensitive.

- Old: `example.com/2013-related-information.html`
- New: `example.com/2014-related-information.html`

Obvious solution is to delete old page and do a 301 redirect to the new page.

Now, can we still keep the old page by giving it a new URL.

1. `example.com/2013-related-information.html` is redirected to `example.com/2014-related-information.html`
2. `example.com/2014-related-information.html` is recreated with a new address such as 
   `example.com/new-2013-related-information.html`

What we are trying to do is to send the user to the fresh page but still not destroying the record copy if someone wants to go and dig up the old information.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach would probably work.  The only problem that could arise would be that the 2013 information might be nearly impossible to dig up.

In situations like this, I don't usually use any redirection at all.  I usually put a notice on the 2013 page that looks like this:

> Information about the [blue widgets 2014 conference can be found here](http://example.com).   This page is about last year's conference and is out of date.

I make the notice a bright color in a big box at the top of the page so that all users see it right away.   With a link from the old page to the new page, Google usually starts to index the new page better too since much of the PageRank from the old page is now being pushed to the new page.

Another way of directing search engines to new content while leaving it for users would be to use a [link rel canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) on the old page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/2014-information" />
```

That lets search engines know that they should be indexing substantially the same content at a different URL while allowing users to see both versions.   It would mean that the 2013 version wouldn't be available in search engines *at all*.

The canonical tag for search engines could be combined with the notice to users.

Comment: Another idea is to have a more-generic page be the main landing page (eg /blue-widgets) which shows the current information, and have the archived pages (/2013/blue-widgets, etc) linked from there. That way, it's easy to focus on the current information (also for search), but still possible to find the rest.